# HTML - How to remove autocomplete bar in android devices

Tags: android, html, input, autocomplete

I'm trying to remove this autocomplete bar in android keyboard

[Android auto complete bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17mQp.png)

I've already tried `autocomplete="off"` but doesn't work, I would like to know if there is a way to hide this autocomplete bar, because it is overlaping my content and the user has to scroll down to see it

this is the code:

```
<input
autocomplete="off"
data-testid="pay-to-view-price-input"
placeholder="0.00"
type="number"
name="price"
step=".01"
class="peer block min-h-12 w-full appearance-none border p-3 px-4 text-sm shadow-sm placeholder:text-passes-gray-light bg-transparent text-left read-only:pointer-events-none"
>
```

Comment: can u share the full code u are using?